# How to add Hibernate HQL/ SQL results (List) to JavaFX TableView (ObservableList) using property?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tableview, javafx-8

I'm using hibernate 5.0.7 and JavaFX For UI's.I get a list of data from database,i tried to show them in a tableView,but no thing shown in tableView.

Here is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
    idproduct serial NOT NULL,
    namefr character varying(50),
    qtyinhand double precision,
    sellprice double precision,
    CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY(idproduct)
)
```

Object Relational Mapping:

```
package model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Product {
    private LongProperty idProduct;
    private StringProperty nameFr;
    private DoubleProperty qtyInHand;
    private DoubleProperty sellPrice;


    public Product() {
        idProduct = new SimpleLongProperty();
        nameFr = new SimpleStringProperty();
        qtyInHand = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        sellPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_seq_gen", sequenceName = "product_idproduct_seq")
    @Column(name = "idproduct", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct.get();
    }

    public LongProperty idProductProperty() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(Long idProduct) {
        this.idProduct.set(idProduct);
    }

    @Column(name = "nameFr")
    public String getNameFr() {
        return nameFr.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameFrProperty() {
        return nameFr;
    }

    public void setNameFr(String nameFr) {
        this.nameFr.set(nameFr);
    }

    @Column(name = "qtyInHand")
    public double getQtyInHand() {
        return qtyInHand.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty qtyInHandProperty() {
        return qtyInHand;
    }

    public void setQtyInHand(double qtyInHand) {
        this.qtyInHand.set(qtyInHand);
    }

    @Column(name = "sellPrice")
    public double getSellPrice() {
        return sellPrice.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty sellPriceProperty() {
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public void setSellPrice(double sellPrice) {
        this.sellPrice.set(sellPrice);
    }
}
```

I'm using hibernate to retrieve the list of products from database:

```
public ObservableList<Product> findAll() {

    try {

        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from product");
        ObservableList<Product> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(query.list());

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that i set the table view to show data:

```
tcID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Long>("idProduct"));
tcNameFR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("nameFr"));
tcQtyInHand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("qtyInHand"));
tcSellPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("sellPrice"));

ProductDAO dao=new ProductDAO();
tableView.getItems().addAll(dao.findAll());
```

After that i can't get item  showed in tablview, instead of that when i debug
i notice that dao.findAll()returns a list with size>0,but table don't show any thing.

Comment: Debug the contents of the list and make sure the elements really are `Product` instances. It's probably better to use a JPQL query here instead of an SQL query, but the SQL version should work (I think...). Assuming you have `Product`s in the list, can you show the rest of the JavaFX code, i.e. creating the table and the columns and displaying the table.

Comment: The debugger show the list as [Object[X]@Refrence] not [Product[X]@Refrence]

Comment: i don't really now how to do it in JPQL ,  i tried Query query = session.createQuery("select t from product t"); but the editor shows that the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: You need the entity name (`Product`) not the table name (`product`). (I should really have said "HQL" instead of "JPQL", since you are using a Hibernate session and not an EntityManager.) Anyway, see answer...

Comment: Thank's it works. i think , i should revise Hibernate fundamentals

Comment: You just have to forget everything you know about databases and SQL ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a SQL query, Hibernate doesn't know to associate your entity with the query. You can do

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from product");
query.addEntity(Product.class);
ObservableList<Product> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(query.list());
```

It's probably better to use a HQL query though:

```
// the really concise, but not very readable "from Product" works as the query too
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Product as p");
ObservableList<Product> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(query.list());
```